# The number of words that can be constructed using $10$ letters of the English alphabet such that all five vowels appear exactly once in the word.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, solution-verification, combinatorics-on-words

The number of words that can be constructed using $10$ letters of the English alphabet such that all five vowels appear exactly once in the word.

The location of the vowel can be chosen in $10C5$ ways and that also can be filled in $5!$ ways, and the remaining $5$ locations can be filled by $pow(21,5)$ ways.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Am I doing it correctly

Comment: Yes, seems to be correct.

Comment: so it will make the solution (10P5) pow(21,5). I'm thinking about whether we can find it directly without going through the conventional method

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: What does the notation $pow(21, 5)$ mean?  Do you mean $21^5$.  That would allow a word with fewer than $10$ distinct letters.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, I agree, the phrase "using $10$ letters" is ambiguous. Does the word *ball* "use" $3$ letters or $4$?

Comment: @BarryCipra  Upon rereading the question, I suspect the author meant a word of length $10$ formed with the letters of the English alphabet in which each vowel appears exactly once.  The wording could have been a lot clearer.

Comment: You can get more directly to 10P5 by choosing where to put the A among the 10 possible places in the word, then where to put the E among the remaining 9 places, the I among the remaining 8 places, the O among the remaining 7 places, and the U among the remaining 6 places, for $10\times9\times8\times7\times6$ possible placements of the vowels. Another way of looking at it, you have positions 1 through 10 in which to place letters; choose some permutation of 5 of these positions and assign the positions of A, E, I, O, U in that way.